# distance between a surface and a plane

Tags: calculus

Hi guys I have another question thats giving me a hard time, can someone please help me out with it ?

I need to find the distance between a surface and a plane. I know that it has to be something with lagrange multipliers but i dont really know how to define the functions for it.

the surface is

$$ z=4x^2+9y^2 $$
and the plane

$$ 4x+6y+z+5=0 $$

thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance of two points $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $d=\sqrt{(x_1-x_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2+(z_1-z_2)^2}$. You need to minimize this under the constraints $g=z_1-4 x_1^2-9 y_1^2=0$ and $h=4x_2+6y_2+z_2+5=0$. Write down the Lagrangian

$$
L=d+\lambda g+\mu h,
$$

and follow the recipe of Lagrange multipliers.

ps: You might as well minimize $d^2$. This way you do not have to worry about the square root.